# Filtering photo library by picture size with Photos framework

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

I am building iOS app for selecting screenshots from user's photo library. The app works, except I can display all photos and I need only screenshots. To detect screenshots I want to match images size with the screen size.

```
var userScreenshots: PHFetchResult!

let screenWidth = view.bounds.size.width * 2
let screenHeight = view.bounds.size.height * 2

let options = PHFetchOptions()
// Following line needs to be changed —>
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(pixelWidth & %d) != 0 || (pixelHeight & %d) != 0", screenWidth, screenHeight)

options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

userScreenshots = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions(options)
```

**Crash:**

```
2015-06-22 23:00:24.540 Altershot[95046:24515142] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate in fetch options: pixelWidth & 0 != 0'
```

Please explain how to define this predicate properly.

Comment: What are you trying to select in your predicate?

Comment: Photos with only particular width and height.

Comment: (pixelWidth == %d AND pixelHeight == %d) ? And I'd suggest that instead of "*2", you may want to use the scale factor (iPhone 6 Plus shouldn't pass through, iPad mini too I think)

Comment: @Larme code is not crashing any more but the result is empty. I'll take the scale advice, thanks.

Comment: `"(pixelWidth == %d AND pixelHeight == %d) OR (pixelWidth == %d AND pixelHeight == %d)" screenWidth, screenHeight , screenHeight, screenWidth`? Could be an issue with orientation.

Comment: No, I found the solution, thank you sir. I'll post my answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is correct code. Note, that's instead of magic number `2` there's `scale` universal property because of iPhone 6 Plus has scale of `3`. I also included landscape screenshots, thanks for the comments. Also, screen size formula was improved to prepare it for iOS 9 multitasking.

```
var userScreenshots: PHFetchResult!

let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width * scale
let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height  * scale

let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(pixelHeight == %d AND pixelWidth == %d) OR (pixelHeight == %d AND pixelWidth == %d)", argumentArray: [screenHeight, screenWidth, screenWidth, screenHeight])

options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

userScreenshots = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions(options)
```